# Recursion challenge - Edabit

Tags: javascript, recursion

The problem wants me to output the string "Edabit" with the number of "a" characters equaling the initial number passed through the function.

I have tried different methods of concatenation but for some reason the string of "a"s seem to ignore their place in the concatenation.

```js
function howManyTimes(num) {
    let str = ''
    
    if (num === 0){
        return `Ed${str}bit`
    }
    else {
        str += 'a'
        return str += howManyTimes(num - 1)
    }
}

console.assert(howManyTimes(0) == "Edbit", "1. Instead got "+howManyTimes(0));
console.assert(howManyTimes(1) == "Edabit", "2. Instead got "+howManyTimes(1));
console.assert(howManyTimes(10) == "Edaaaaaaaaaabit", "3. Instead got "+howManyTimes(10));
```

Comment: Recursion seems inappropriate here. Why not `\`Ed${"a".repeat(num)}bit\``?

Comment: I agree with ggorlen, though this may be because part of the challenge of the problem is to use recursion.

Comment: It's true, there is a long history of the computer science education system applying recursion to inappropriate uses. Here, recursion is less readable, slower and risks blowing the stack to do something that's fast, easy to read and can handle any sized input with a builtin function or loop.

Comment: It's often easy to critique educators, or anyone else for that matter, for their attempts at creating examples to teach a subject matter.  If the base line goal is to teach a concept, the appropriateness of an approach can be ignored until the basic knowledge is obtained.

Comment: @Taplar I'm speaking as a CS educator and I agree, there's great pressure to oversimplify or misapply a concept initially, then give the full truth later, but I believe in the long run this approach tends to do more harm than good. There are ways to motivate recursion with real scenarios that students can understand intuitively. For example, printing a tree of Reddit-style comments is a far stronger motivator. It's easy to grasp (everyone sees this daily) and code. Show them a `Comment` object with `text` and `children` list containing other `Comments` and off you go--trees, recursion and OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function howManyTimes(num, str) {
  if (!str) str = '';
  
  if (num > 0) {
    return howManyTimes(num - 1, str + 'a');
  } else {
    return `Ed${str}bit`;
  }
}

console.log(howManyTimes(8));
```

One issue is that your recursion is always appending the result of the method to an `a`.  Rather than doing that, pass along the aggregated string to then be used once you reach the end.

Comment: This is a good answer, though I feel like it is cheating the problem to add another parameter.

Comment: @NateLevin Then come up with an alternative.  Multiple solutions improve questions, :)

Comment: The intent of my comment was not to be rude, sorry if it sounded that way. That is all I could come up with aswell.

Comment: @NateLevin Nah, I didn't take it as rude at all.

Comment: @NateLevin: one way to avoid the second parameter is to use a wrapper function around the recursive one.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can always separate out the part that can use straightforward recursion from a shell that calls that part and does something with the result.   For instance,

```js
const nAs = (n) =>
  n == 0 ? '' : nAs (n - 1) + 'a'

const howManyTimes = (n) =>
  `Ed${nAs (n)}bit`

console .log (howManyTimes (0))
console .log (howManyTimes (1))
console .log (howManyTimes (10))
```

Of course I would only write it this way in a recursion challenge.  For this example, there are more straightforward ways to write this, including `` const howManyTimes = (n) => `Ed${'a'.repeat(n)}bit` ``